# Одновременная задержка потоков

Tags: c#

Есть глобальное число i, запускается несколько Thread и каждый циклично увеличивает i на 1. Как сделать, чтобы через каждые 5 прибавлений (i = 5, 10, 15...) потоки одновременно замораживались на n секунд и потом одновременно продолжали работу?

Comment: Мне кажется вам `Barrier` должен подойти, вернее может два таких барьера - один после счёта и один после паузы. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.barrier?view=net-6.0

Comment: @CrazyElf тут простой ManualResetEventSlim справится.

Comment: @aepot а вы могли бы привести пример для моей задачи?

Comment: Вы начните решать, читайте документацию, и если не получится, покажите код, попробуем доработать.